Apache virtual host pointing to intermediary document root
I have this fodler structure:
Path to my laravel project:
/home/name/workspace/myProject
Path to my intermediary indexes:
/home/name/workspace/indexes/indexOne
/home/name/workspace/indexes/indexTwo
The two folders, indexOne and index Two contain a .env file and public fodler woth a index.php and a .haccess file.
I want my apache2 virtual host to point to one of my intermediary indexes public folder and use the env in that configuration.
If I make my virtual host to point to the /home/name/workspace/myProject/public it works but this is not what I need as that is the normal configuration.
My Virtual host config.
<VirtualHost *:8002>
        ServerName dev-myApp.be
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/name/workspace/indexes/indexOne/public

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <Directory "/home/name/workspace/indexes/indexOne/public">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>


This is my index.php from /home/name/workspace/indexes/indexOne/public:
<?php
// Redirect to the main index.php file in the project's public folder
$redirectTo = '/home/name/workspace/myProject/public/';

if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $redirectTo) === false) {
    header('Location: ' . $redirectTo);
    exit;
}
?>

This is my .htaccess file from /home/name/workspace/indexes/indexOne/public
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

I get different errors depending on the config I try from 404 to to many redirects to the respoins beeing the content of the index.php file.

You have your redirect pointing to a file path, not a URL/path. It will redirect to domain.com/home/name/workspace/myProject/public/, which of course is incorrect.

@aynber I did that because I want to redirect to my index.php from where the code is:
/home/name/workspace/myProject/public/index.php.
How can I make it point to my code or the public folder from myProject ?

Based on the answer from aynber I managed to solve the problem. I had to change the intermidiate index.php file located at /home/name/workspace/indexes/indexOne/pubic.
This is the solution:

?php
define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));
$envPath = '/home/name/workspace/indexes/indexOne/.env';   putenv("APP_ENV_PATH=$envPath");
require '/home/name/workspace/myProject/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once '/home/name/workspace/myProject/bootstrap/app.php';
$app->useStoragePath('/home/name/workspace/indexes/indexOne/storage');
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
$response = $kernel->handle($request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture());
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
